# Convert json date to date in java

Tags: java, json, date

How to convert json date to java.util.Date

```
{"date":31,"day":4,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"month":11,"seconds":0,"time":2145805200000,"timezoneOffset":-420,"year":137}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: you just parse `time` value `2145805200000` and create date object like `java.util.Date(2145805200000l)` will give you the corresponding date. Since `java.util.Date` is timezone independent no need to consider `timezoneOffset`

Answer (score 0):

With a quick Google search, I managed to find this webpage: [CLICK](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ISO8601dateparsingutility.htm)
The 'parse' method returning a `Date` shows you how to use the `SimpleDateFormat` class in Java which is used to parse a String into a `Date`.
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

## No JSON Date

No such thing as a JSON date. JSON has [very few data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example), none of which are date-time related.

## Count Since Epoch

That `time` item with value `2145805200000` is probably a count since [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29). The two questions are: What epoch? and What granularity of count?

Commonly used are [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) since the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

The java.time framework built into Java 8 and later can translate such number. The `Instant` class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
long sinceEpoch = 2145805200000L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( sinceEpoch );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant );
```

> instant: 2037-12-30T17:00:00Z

That value may be close to the other fields in your JSON, but is not quite a match.

Your JSON has an field `timezoneOffset` with value `-420`. If we interpret that number as an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) in minutes, that would mean 7 hours. We can ask java.time to adjust the Instant into such an offset.

Normally we would want to use a time zone for this adjustment. A time zone is an offset-from-UTC *plus* a set of historic rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). But in this case we have only the offset-from-UTC. So rather than use a `ZoneId` we use the subclass `ZoneOffset`. The result is a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours ( 7 );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneOffset );
```

Dump to console.

```
    System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant + " + zoneOffset: " + zoneOffset + " = zdt: " + zdt );
```

> instant: 2037-12-30T17:00:00Z + zoneOffset: +07:00 = zdt: 2037-12-31T00:00+07:00

That gets us to the beginning of the day on the 31st of December in 2037. Still not an exact match to the other JSON fields.

But if that `-420` was meant as being 7 hours *behind* UTC rather than ahead, we need to change that offset from `7` hours to a negative `-7` hours. Then the results would be:

> instant: 2037-12-30T17:00:00Z + zoneOffset: -07:00 = zdt: 2037-12-30T10:00-07:00

If you knew more about your JSON data, then perhaps a solution could be found.